# Using GANs to generate data for sparse datasets

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, generative-adversarial-network

I have been recently introduced to the applications of ML in Cybersecurity, and I was interested in working on an application of GANs to generate data for sparse datasets
(Something like this https://becominghuman.ai/deep-learning-can-tackle-the-problem-of-sparse-data-by-augmenting-available-data-e9a4e0f1fc92)

However, I am not aware of the sort of datasets that can be used for this purpose. Could someone guide me through a few example datasets I can use to train a GAN on and to generate data? Are text datasets any good for GAN related generation?
My objective here is to simply understand how this whole process should work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't clear enough. I wish to know
a) Are there any datasets that contain a lot of benign examples but very few fraudulent/adversarial data points? 
b) Is using GANs for text datasets a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across [this repository](https://github.com/jivoi/awesome-ml-for-cybersecurity#-datasets)? I guess it contains datasets and more!